# Typewriter text in sections with ACM "sig-alternate" document class

Tags: typewriter

I would like to put a `\texttt{}` block in a section, e.g.

```
\section{Algorithm \texttt{FSG}}
```

But the problem of this approach is that the text inside the`\texttt{}` block does not inherit the size and boldness of the surrounding text, at least with the ACM `sig-alternate` document class. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: The Computer Modern Typewriter font doesn't have a boldface version; the size, however, *is* inherited.

Comment: How can I specify that a block of text has to be displayed in Computer Modern Typewriter?

Comment: Well, if you don't change the font setup, saying `\texttt{something}` typesets "something" in CM Typewriter.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I am using ACM's `sig-alternate` documentclass, but I am not saying a thing about fonts and stuff like that. The size of the typewritten text, however is noticeably smaller than the rest of the section title.

Comment: That's a problem with the `sig-alternate` class that's written in what I wouldn't define good LaTeX programming. :(

Comment: That's SO unfortunate, since I **have** to use this class! Well, I'll find out an another way... thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately the `sig-alternate` class uses a peculiar<sup>1</sup> way to set the document fonts.

In particular, the `\texttt` macro selects the font family `aett` (which belongs to a definitely obsolete package) at size 9pt, independent of context. So you have two problems.

1. Use a boldface version of the Typewriter font.
2. Increase the font size in section titles.

### Solution to problem 1

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ttfamily}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}
```

### Solution to problem 2

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\sectt[1]{{\fontsize{13}{12}\bfseries\ttfamily#1}}
```

### Example document

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ttfamily}{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sectt[1]{{\fontsize{13}{12}\bfseries\ttfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Algorithm \protect\sectt{FSG}}
Algorithm \texttt{FSG}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Newer problems

Due to how the class is written, you won't be able to make a table of contents if a command such as `\sectt` appears in a section title. But this would happen also with `\sqrt` and other seemingly innocuous commands

The editors of the conference to which you're submitting the paper may not be happy with these changes.

---

<sup>1</sup> The adjective "peculiar" should be read as "blatantly wrong".