# Problem With Fonts

Tags: fonts

I am submitting a paper at CIKM. So I have downloaded the `sig-alternate.cls` and `sig-alternate.tex` files. But problem is that while compiling them the following errors are coming:

```
******LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/aett/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/aett/m/n' instead on input line 414.**
...
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.****
```

I am not getting any clue to fix the error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Possible duplicate/work-around: [Typewriter text in sections with ACM `sig-alternate` document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87891/5764)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The warning says that the font `T1/aett/bx/n` (font ae monospaced bold) was unavailable (it doesn't exist) and that instead LaTeX used font `T1/aett/m/n` (font ae monospaced). The `ae` fonts are based on the default Computer Modern fonts, where the monospaced version has no bold; these fonts are loaded by default by the `sig-alternate` class.

Basically, you can't have bold monospaced text with this set of fonts because this particular font doesn't exist.

As Werner commented above, a solution is available [at this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87891/24113).

Comment: Is there a simple way to suppress these warnings? Or do something about them?

Comment: @PontusGranström Did you read the link ChrisS provided?

Comment: @cfr That link was provided in response to Pontus' comment.